# Number of even terms in a polynomial related to an exponent

Tags: polynomials, summation

For a polynomial $(x_1+x_2+...+x_N)^{2k}$, I am trying to show that the number of fully even terms is $≤a_kN^k$, where $a_k$ only depends on $k$ and is constant for a constant $k$. When I say "fully even terms" I mean terms where only even exponents appear.

For every term, the exponents have to add up to 2k. So I broke it down into all possible exponent combinations. E.g., the combination where all exponents equal 2, and there are k terms. For each of these combinations, I count the number of terms. I determined that for a combination with $i$ elements, there are ${N \choose i}$ terms. So I determined the total number of terms is $\sum_{i=1}^t{N \choose i}$, where $t = min(N,k)$.

But I have no idea how to compare this to the exponential expression I want. Is what I've done so far correct? And how can I proceed?

Comment: It looks like you're asking for the number of partitions of $2k$ into at most $N$ even parts.  Can't you divide everything by $2$ and ask for the number of partitions of $k$ into at most $N$ parts?  This is well known, I think.  Anyway, it will be easier to Google.

Comment: @saulspatz That would work, but it seems like there's no closed form formula for that. I found some stuff on google, but I'm not sure how I can use it to answer this question.

Comment: I've been googling, too, and finding the same stuff as you are.  Looking at https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196885812000127, one would guess that (in the reformulated problem) that there's a bound of the form $ck^{N-1},$ not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

The terms you want to count are the terms of the form $x_1^{2k_1}\cdots x_N^{2k_n}$ where $k_i \ge 0, i=1,...,N,$ and $\sum{k_i} = k.$  This is exactly the number of terms in $(x_1+x_2+ \cdots x_N)^k$ or $N^k.$  We get a one-to-one correspondence by dividing/multiplying all the exponents by $2.$

My comment about partitions was way off base.  In partitions, the order does not matter, but here you want to distinguish between $x_1^4x_2^2$ and $x_1^2x_2^4,$ for example.

Comment: But there are also terms like $x_1^1x_2^2x_1^3$ which is not in this correspondence？

Comment: @RodH I'm not saying the expressions are the same, but that they have the same number of terms.  Let $y_i=x_i^2$, $i=1,2,\dots,n$.  Then you want to count terms of the form $y_1^{k_1}\cdots y_N^{k_N}$, which is the number of terms in  $(y_1+y_2+ \cdots y_N)^k$.  Same thing.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the problem, I thought here ‘order’ means there is difference between like $x_1^2x_2^4$ and $x_1x_2^4x_1$ therefore we take coefficients into account.

Comment: @RodH Oh, I misread your comment before; now I understand.  I just meant the order of the exponents.  The variables always occur in their natural order.